# String split using RegEx in R

Tags: regex, r, split

Assume we've got the following string.

```
str <- '<a><b><c>';
```

I'd need to split it so that the output is a vector of `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`.

Essentially I'd probably need a RegEx split function that takes out instances of `<(*)>` from the original string and add them in a new vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str <- '<a><b><c>'
str <- gsub('<|>','',str)
str <- unlist(strsplit(str,'',fixed=TRUE))  # or: strsplit(str,'',fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
```

gives:

```
> str
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

In respons to your comment:

```
str2 <- '<ab><bc><cd>'
str2 <- unlist(strsplit(str2,'><',fixed=TRUE))  # or: strsplit(str2,'><',fixed=TRUE)[[1]]
str2 <- gsub('<|>','',str2)
```

gives:

```
> str2
[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"
```

Comment: I'm too slow at typing - the same idea, but using `substr`: `unlist(strsplit(substr(str, 2, nchar(str) - 1), "><"))`

Comment: Or `stringi::stri_split_regex(str2, '<|>', omit_empty = TRUE)[[1]]`

Answer (score 2):

**1) strsplit/gsub** Remove the `<` characters and then split by `>` like this.  (One might have expected that this would leave a zero character component at the end but fortunately because of the way `strsplit` works this does not occur.)  This solution is particularly short and uses no packages.

```
unlist(strsplit(gsub("<", "", str), ">"))
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**2) scan/chartr** Replace `<` and `>` characters with a space and then use scan to read in what is left.  This solution uses no packages and is particularly straight-forward but depends on the fields not containing spaces:

```
scan(textConnection(chartr("<>", "  ", str)), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
## [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**3) strapplyc**  `strapplyc` in the gsubfn package extracts the fields that match a regular expression.     (stringr package also provides a similar function and base R provides `regmatches` which can also do this too but a bit awkwardly.)   This solution is very short but does use a package.

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(str, "[^<>]+", simplify = c)
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `gsub` '><' for something else. I chose a space. This is what you will `strsplit` on later. Then, then remove '>' and '<'. You can then `strsplit` on space. Use `unlist` if needed.

```
str1 <- '<a><b><c>';
str1 <-gsub('><',' ',str1)
str1 <-gsub('>|<','',str1)
strsplit(str1,' ')
#"a" "b" "c"
```

Comment: Why do you keep changing your question? The solution works for your question. Go with @Jaap's answer, which he also updated after you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can split using `strsplit` and a regex `/[<>]+/` and then filter out all the empty results with `lapply`:

```
str <- '<ab><bc><cd>'
unlist(lapply(strsplit(str,"[<>]+"), function(x){x[!x ==""]}))
//[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"
```

Or simply remove the first empty arg:

```
unlist(strsplit(str,"[<>]+"))[-1]
//[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str2, '[a-z]+')[[1]]
#[1] "ab" "bc" "cd"
```